# Invoke multiple entry points in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack with typescript and babel to manage my client side web application.

I want to have a `vendor.js` file for 3rd party scripts, a `main.js` file, and per-page scripts I can load as needed to provide specific functionality for a page.

All the scripts are compiling as I would expect, but only the `vendor.js` file is actually getting invoked. The others are compiled, but never invoked.

Below is my `webpack.config.js` file.

```
'use strict';

let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './assets/js/main.ts',
    "single-page": './assets/js/src/new-loan.ts',
    vendor: [
      "svg4everybody"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: './public/assets/js/[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: Infinity
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
}
```

And an example of one of the page-specific files. Ideally, when loaded, this file would trigger an `alert` notification on the page.

```
webpackJsonp([1],[
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    'use strict';

    alert('test');

/***/ }
]);
```

I can see /why/ the alert isn't triggering (the module function is never invoked), but I can't figure out how to configure webpack to work how I'd like it to.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: How about creating a single entry which imports all the others?

Comment: I don't want to load everything in every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `CommonsChunkPlugin` is overwriting the `vendor` bundle in your config. Try changing the name of `CommonsChunkPlugin` to `common` from `vendor`, and include the `common` bundle in all of your files, before every other bundle. If you use the `CommonsChunkPlugin`, only the common bundle will contain the core webpack module loader helper functions, so it must be embedded in every page.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "common",
  minChunks: Infinity
})
```